# Aliasing a Route in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, alias

I would like to alias the way the name of a route is displayed to the user in the address bar, in my routes at present i have

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'pages/my_portfolio'
  match '/my_portfolio', :to => 'pages#my_portfolio'
end
```

So i have a pages controller that has all my static pages, but rather than have the url show as

```
/my_portfolio
```

I would like it to show as

```
/my-portfolio
```

I have tried

```
match '/my_portfolio', :to => 'pages#my_portfolio', :as => 'my-portfolio'
```

but get an error

```
Invalid route name: 'my-portfolio' (ArgumentError)
```

How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Try like this `match '/my_portfolio', :to => 'pages#my_portfolio' ,:as => 'my-portfolio'`

Comment: I had tried that previously but get the error Invalid route name: 'my-portfolio' (ArgumentError)

Comment: What happens if you rewrite `match '/my_portfolio'` to `match '/my-portfolio'`? Like this:

`get 'pages/my-portfolio'`
`match '/my-portfolio', :to => 'pages#my_portfolio'`

Comment: i get undefined local variable or method `my_portfolio_path', so if i then change the route to pages_my_portfolio_path in the address bar the route is displayed as /pages/my_portfolio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
match '/my-portfolio', :to => 'pages#my_portfolio', :as => 'my_portfolio'
```

You could run `rake routes` to confirm that you achieved what you want.

Hope I could help.